# Right arithmetic shift does not work properly

Tags: verilog

```
if(Op_ex == 5'b11011 || Op_ex==5'b11100 || Op_ex==5'b11101 || Op_ex==5'b11110 || Op_ex==5'b11111 )
 begin
    temp_carry = 1'b0;
    ans_ex = A   >>>   B;
    flag[3] = ans_ex[0]^ans_ex[1]^ans_ex[2]^ans_ex[3]^ans_ex[4]^ans_ex[5]^ans_ex[6]^ans_ex[7];  //flag[3] = parity
    flag[2] = 0;                                                  //flag[2] = overflow  
    flag[0] = 0;
    if(ans_ex == 8'b00000000)
        begin
            flag[1] = 1'b1;                                   //flag[1] = zero
        end
    else
        begin
            flag[1] = 1'b0;
        end
        data_out = reg_data;
 end         
end
```

If I put `A = 8'hC0` and `B = 8'h01` then it will give me output as 60, instead of e0 in hexadecimal .

Comment: How are `A` and `B` defined?

Comment: A and B are 8 bit long and A = 8'hC0 and B=8'h01 so output would be 8'he0 but it gives me output as 8'h60 it only shifts registers to right not doing arithmetic operation

Comment: A is input and it is defined as input A[7:0];

Comment: B is input and it is defined as input B[7:0];

Comment: You need to show the declarations of all signals in your example. An I think you meant to say that A and B are declared as `input [7:0] A,B;` there is a big difference. Please update your original post instead of adding comments.

Comment: IF you want to see my whole code than i can mail you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A` is unsigned. The sign extinction of an unsigned is always 0.
Make `A` (possibly B well) a signed value. Two was to do so:

- `input signed [7:0] A,B`
- `ans_ex = $signed(A) >>> B;`

---

<sub>FYI:

`(Op_ex == 5'b11011 || Op_ex==5'b11100 || Op_ex==5'b11101 || Op_ex==5'b11110 || Op_ex==5'b11111 )` can be simplified to `(Op_ex >= 5'b11011)`

`flag[3] = ans_ex[0]^ans_ex[1]^ans_ex[2]^ans_ex[3]^ans_ex[4]^ans_ex[5]^ans_ex[6]^ans_ex[7];` can be simplified to: `flag[3] = ^ans_ex;` or `flag[3] = ^ans_ex[7:0];`</sub>

Comment: I try this but my output remains same it didi not give right arithmetic shift it gives only right shift not right arithmetci shift

Comment: thx greg it works on signed numbers but did not work on unsigned numbers